# Linear transformations - Find x such that T(x) = b

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need help with a problem in Linear Algebra:

Given a matrix
 $$A
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 1\\
    1 & -1 & 1\\
    2 & 1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$$

and a vector

$$b
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    4\\
    1\\
    4
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Find $x$ such that $T(x) = b$

**What I have tried:**

I know that $T(x) = Ax = b$, so plugging in yields Ax = b. Rewriting as an augmented matrix and simplifying, we get the reduced row echelon form

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

However, I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the reduced row echelon form 
 $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  \end{bmatrix},$$
which gives the solution
 $$
  x=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}.$$
Indeed,
$$Ax
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 1\\
    1 & -1 & 1\\
    2 & 1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    4\\
    1\\
    4
  \end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Find $A^{-1}$

Then $a= A^{-1}.b$

This could be a method to find $a$ if $A$ is non singular matrix, because

$a= A^{-1}.b$

$  \implies b=A.a$